# Anything better than ruby alchemy for extracting keywords?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, data-mining, extract, keyword

I've currently written an algorithm in Ruby based on the arc90 readability code to extract an article from a web page.

Now that I have the article, I want to extract keywords and specific information from it (names, author, etc)

I heard Alchemy was a great ruby gem for doing this though it consumes a lot of resources. Are there any better gems I can use for this?

Comment: i think the 'alchemy' keyword refers to Adobe's Alchemy project, not the Ruby Gem.  See the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/alchemy/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [OpenCalais gem](http://github.com/abhay/calais) which provides similar capability. In addition to entity extraction it can also detect events and relations between entities. It's not lightweight, though I couldn't tell if it's better or worse than Alchemy as I haven't used the Alchemy gem. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've gone and written my own gem for OpenCalais: https://github.com/RedFred7/dover_to_calais

Answer (score 9):

fast, leightweight and easy-to-use gem for extracting keywords from longer content:

https://rubygems.org/gems/highscore

i use it in production, works like a charm.

The question is a bit older, but i'll leave this here for others who will come from google to see this question.